# Markov’s inequality and Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let X be a random variable having the Poisson distribution with parameter 1. What does Markov’s inequality (p.72) imply about the probability P{X ≥ 2}?

Comment: Markov's inequality applies to all r.v., so it utilizes *little* characteristics of a specific probability distribution.  As a result, the upper bound given by Markov/Chebylshev inequality is often too weak.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Markov's Inequality** states that if $X$ is a nonnegative random variable and
>   $c > 0$, then $$P(X \geq c) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{c}.$$

We have $X \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$, meaning that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \lambda = 1$. We can set $c = 2$. Then, we obtain the bound

$$P(X \geq 2) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Therefore, we conclude $P(X \geq 2)$ will be at most $0.5$.