# Calculate Markov and Chebyshev bound

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

We have a program consisting of $n = 100$ modules of code.

$X_i$ = number of errors on the ith module of code

Suppose that $X_i ∼ Poisson(1)$ are i.i.d.

Let $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $ be the total number of errors.

I need to compute Markov and Chebyshev bounds for $Pr(Y \geq 80)$ but I don't know how.

For instance, I know Markov inequality is:

$$\Pr(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$$

And [I have seen that for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018526/720875) for $Poisson(1)$ I could replace $E(x)$ for 1, but I'm not sure what I should replace it for in this case, since it is the $E(Y)$.

If the expected value of $X$ is 1, should the expected value of $Y$ be 100?

Cause this doesn't look correct:

$$\Pr(Y \geq 80) \leq \frac{100}{80}$$

**Edit**

Ok, so since by the comments it seems to be correct. I need to calculate Chebyshev.

For that I need the $Var(Y)$, since $Y$ is a compound poisson distribution [I have seen this formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86408/264581):

$$Var(Y) =(\sigma^2+\mu^2)\lambda$$

And I know $\sigma$ and $\mu$ for $X$ are $\lambda$, so:

$$Var(Y) = 2$$

Then the formula is:

$$\Pr(Y \geq a) \leq \frac{Var(Y)}{(a - E(Y))^2}$$

And I should get:

$$\Pr(Y \geq 80) \leq \frac{2}{400}$$

Is this correct? Should I do anything else on this last formula?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Could you explain what you tried? Do you know the definition of these inequalities ?  Where do you have a problem ?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues I have added a bit more on what my thoughts are, my problem is I don't understand what is the expected value for Y, and therefor can't apply the formulas

Comment: I thinks it's correct since 1<10/8. It's just that this inequality doesn't provide a tighter bound

Comment: Thanks for the addition. The computation of the markov bound is correct, but indeed useless in your case. Checbychev's bound uses the variance and should provide a tigher result

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLesgourgues I added an attempt to the second formula

Comment: You made a mistake when looking at $Y$. It is not a compound Poisson. A Compound Poisson distribution is for the sum of a number of independent identically-distributed random variables, where **the number of terms** to be added is itself a Poisson-distributed variable. In your case it's much simpler, as you are adding a fixed number $n$ of random variables. 

With the assumption that all $X_i$ are i.i.d, $Y$ follows a $Poisson(n)$, hence $E(Y)=V(Y)=n$. Dos this help?